# How do I JOIN one-to-many tables using NotORM lib

Tags: php, mysql, database, notorm

i'm using NotOrm lib for working with data in the database.
I have to follow the instructions here 
http://www.sitepoint.com/database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm/

but did not solve my problem
Here is my data structure:

```
Tables 
   -members 
           ---Indexes 
            PRIMARY id 

   -cards
          ---Indexes 
            PRIMARY id
            INDEX   member_id
          ---Foreign keys
            member_id   members(id) CASCADE CASCADE
```

I used sql command

```
ALTER TABLE  `cards` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `member_id` ) REFERENCES  `xxx`.`members` (`id`)
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

my code

```
$cards = $this->db->cards();    
    foreach($cards as $c){
        //echo "here";
        echo $c->members["member_id"];
    }
```

and response is

> => Message: Undefined index: members_id

Is my data structure correct for using NotORM ?
i want to result from SQL as:

> select members.f1, members.f2
>   from members
>   join cards
>   on members.id = cards.member_id
>   where cards.email like '%%' or cards.phone like '%%'

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also asked and answered [in the forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/notorm/SOCUlR7YMzY).